# Two-column table or dl?

Tags: html

I have the following content I need to mark up:

**Course requirements**:

[image: course requirements]

and **dates**:

[image: dates]

The question is whether to use a two-column `table` element or a `dl` ([description list](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element)) element. I would like a response for each specific instance, and then a response *in general* if possible. I've always had trouble deciding on these elements, especially if the `table` doesn't have (or need) headers.

Note: My question is *not* how I should style these elements. I'll get to the presentation after I decide on the semantics.

EDIT: Answers that adhere to the HTML5 draft are favored over answers that adhere to the old HTML4 recommendation.

Answer (score 38):

Rule of thumb: if you can put a header on the table version, it should **not** be a definition list.

Another rule of thumb: If you can **not** put a header on the table version, it should be a definition list.

That's because a good list should make no sense as a table and vice-versa. Here's an example of what a good definition list looks like:

**Height**
180cm
**Weight**
180kg
**Telephone**
555-5555
123-4567

When we try to convert this to a table we get...

```
Terms         Definitions
------------------------
Height        180cm 
Weight        180kg 
Telephones    555-5555 
              123-4567
```

Look at the column headers; it's just "terms" and "definitions"!

Height, weight and telephone are completely different things with completely different definitions attached to them. Where in the world do 555-5555 and 180cm belong in the same column? It makes no sense!

However, sometimes you see tables like this

```
Height        |    180cm 
Weight        |    180kg 
Telephones    |    555-5555 
              |    123-4567
```

There are no terms and definitions as header, the headers of the cells are assumed to be on the first column. IMHO when you have a table like that you are using tables wrong and you should use a definition list instead. For a table to be justifiable it must have multiple rows and each cell of each row can be defined by its column's headers.

Something like this for example:

```
Name    Height    Weight
------------------------
John    180cm     180kg
Jack    170cm     155kg
```

John and Jack are names. 180cm and 170cm are heights. 180kg and 155kg are weights. You have an important relationship of cells with their rows and columns, and you can't put this in a definition list without severing that important relationship. So in this case a table should be used.

TL;DR:
The two column table in your question can have headers. So it should be a table.

See:

```
Class                         Required Points
---------------------------------------------
Cohort Teaching               10 pts.
Cohort Research and Report    20 pts.
```

Comment: Be careful with definition lists if the website wants to be accessible (every website should ;)). There are issues with screen readers, see https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/definition-lists-v-tables

Answer (score 7):

The table element would best suit your needs, in terms of semantics.

W3C states that the `table` element "[allows authors to arrange data -- text, preformatted text, images, links, forms, form fields, other tables, etc. -- into rows and columns of cells](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)", which is exactly how you formatted your example.

The W3C states that the `dl` tag is for lists that "[consist of two parts: a term and a description](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.3)". Since "10 pts." is not the description of the term "Cohort Teaching", this is not the proper element to use.

Comment: No actually a dl is perfect. From the spec you link it also states 'Another application of DL, for example, is for marking up dialogues, with each DT naming a speaker, and each DD containing his or her words.' And in HTML5 they are called description lists which further supports this http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/dl.html

Comment: @Alistair, It's true that you can use the `dl` tag for this purpose, but semantically it's not correct. Marking up dialogues (as you referenced) is similar to a term-description grouping in that there is a name-dialogue grouping, however the OP is not concerned with dialogue and is describing a Table of Contents which is structured in a row x column design, a perfect fit for a `table`. You would also end up over-styling the `dl` in the end to make it look similar to a `table`.

Comment: I'm still undecided about the two. Look at the code examples in [the HTML5 docs on the dl element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element). It's not only reserved for term-description pairs.

Comment: Some of the examples on that page (like the set of instructions) I would not even use a `dl`, an unordered list would be more appropriate. If you're still undecided I would say choose one, be able to defend your decision, and keep coding away. If you have better insight in the future you can always go back and change it.

Answer (score 2):

These look like tables to me. A dl is used as name,value pair list where each name can have one or more values. I don't think you can place a correlation between multiple groups for example

```
<dl>
<dt>Class</dt>
<dd>Cohort Teaching</dd>
<dd>My other Class</dd>
<dt>Points</dt>
<dd>10</dd>
<dd>20</dd>
</dl>
```

There is nothing in the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element) which indicates that Cohort Teaching is related to the 10 points. Each group is self contained.

At the very least I would not mark it up using a DL as I have done. I would use a table.

Comment: Yes, I agree in a `dl` there is no correlation between a `dd` in one group and a `dd` in another group. the only correlation available is between a `dt` and a following `dd`. Thus I would agree that one shouldn't mark up the content using a `dl` in the way that you did in your example. However, one might be able to put each entry in the "left column" in a `dt` and ditto "right column" in `dd`. For example `<dt>Cohort Teaching</dt><dd>10 pts</dd>` etc. This way the correlation would be made explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a two-column table since you are not defining anything in your two examples (you are displaying key:value type information). The dl tag (in term of semantics) is used for definitions exclusively or descriptions. For example, some people comment their code using <dl> tags.

When trying to chose you can say to yourself: does "this" (e.g. Cohort #) means "this" (10 feb)

Answer (score -1):

You could use a styled `UL` with a fixed with `label` + your data.