# 2 column table or definition list for semantically correct HTML?

Tags: html, html-table, semantic-markup

I frequently have to display a series of name-value pairs, as I'm sure most web developers face. Typically in the form of properties. What is the semantically correct HTML way to do this?

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td><td>Jimmy</td>
      <td>Age</td><td>33</td>
      <td>Gender</td><td>Male</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

or

```
<dl>
  <dt>Name</dt><dd>Jimmy</dd>
  <dt>Age</dt><dd>33</dd>
  <dt>Gender</dt><dd>Male</dd>
</dl>
```

Or is there another better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In HTML5, the most specific element for your use case would be the [`dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) (bold emphasis mine):

> The `dl` element represents an association list consisting of zero or more **name-value groups** (a description list).

> Name-value groups may be terms and definitions, metadata topics and values, questions and answers, or **any other groups of name-value data**.

Answer (score 0):

I think `table` is correct semantically.

Based on w3c, we can tell that `table` element '[allows authors to arrange data -- text, preformatted text, images, links, forms, form fields, other tables, etc. -- into rows and columns of cells.](http://[1]:%20http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html)'

However, `dl` element '[consist of two parts: a term and a description](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.3)', which is not your case.

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900571/two-column-table-or-dl)